Custom GrpcSecurityMechanism does not block requests with no authorization key in metadata
I have the following custom GrpcSecurityMechanism implemented:
package ...;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import io.grpc.Metadata;
import io.quarkus.grpc.auth.GrpcSecurityMechanism;
import io.quarkus.security.UnauthorizedException;
import io.quarkus.security.credential.TokenCredential;
import io.quarkus.security.identity.request.AuthenticationRequest;
import io.quarkus.security.identity.request.TokenAuthenticationRequest;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;

@Singleton
public class GrpcAuthNValidator implements GrpcSecurityMechanism {

  private static final Metadata.Key<String> AUTHORIZATION =
      Metadata.Key.of("Authorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);

  private static final String bearerTokenPrefix = "Bearer";

  @Override
  public boolean handles(Metadata metadata) {
    return true; // Always handle the request
  }

  @Override
  public AuthenticationRequest createAuthenticationRequest(Metadata metadata) {
    String authString = metadata.get(AUTHORIZATION);
    if (authString != null && authString.startsWith(bearerTokenPrefix)) {
      String token = authString.substring((bearerTokenPrefix + " ").length());
      return new TokenAuthenticationRequest(new TokenCredential(token, bearerTokenPrefix));
    } else {
      throw new UnauthorizedException("Token not found");
    }
  }
}

I am using a BlockingStub to call my gRPC service (which is within a docker container). I am using quarkus.grpc.server.use-separate-server=false.
When I don't provide the "Authorization" key in metadata, I was expecting the requests to fail with UNAUTHENTICATED. For some reason, the request gets through successfully.
Am I missing something?
Thank you in advance
